# How do I make a Java application retrieve data from a remote Drupal website?

Tags: java, drupal

I have a java enterprise application that needs to retrieve data (HTML and PDFs nothing to complex) from a remote Drupal website. Is there a supported way to do that or should i build something custom for that? Can anyone point me on the write direction, Thanks in advance.

Comment: Speaking of write direction, what have you tried?

Comment: @SaviourSelf Content API the problem with this is because is in beta and it doesn't look it has a clear way to retrieve PDF's or HTML, I am also taking a look on feeds but didn't get any concrete yet.